# Wrong Positions using fread()

Tags: c, cs50, fread

I'm using this code to read a file.

```
char *infile = argv[1];
int size = 4000000;
FILE *card = fopen(infile, "r");
int *temp2 = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int)); 

fread(temp2, sizeof(int), size, card);
```

I'm learning to code with CS50. An exercise is to read a file byte to byte, I'm using `fread()` and storing the result into an array, the problem is the array is `int` and the values are stored in wrong position.

Example: If the first four `int` bytes of the file are: `40 50 25 80`

After `fread()` in the array the item is storage 80 25 50 40.

I need to fix the order.

Comment: So you do not want to write the bytes to the array as they are in the file and instead turn every four of them around? I am not sure you actually want that, but what is keeping you from doing it? You might consider making a [mre] of what you have, because sometimes people here can guess from your code at what your actual goal is. Try to make it without cs5 headers, because most here do not have that.

Comment: Is there a specail reason for reading chunks of int size (which I think causes your problems)? Why not read chunks of byte/char size (1) and stop bothering about weird orders caused by you, your teacher and your compiler disagreeing on endianess.?

Comment: To put it differently, why not `fread(temp2, sizeof(char), size, card);`?

Comment: @bruno Thanks for de-escalating. My respect. I notice now that I was getting agitated. Good style.

Answer (score 1):

> An exercise is to read a file byte to byte

so put the result in an array of byte/char rather than in an array of `int`.

Also *read a file byte to byte* means to use `fgetc` or to read 1 byte when using `fread`

> Example: If the first four int bytes of the file are: 40 50 25 80
>
> After fread() in the array the item is storage 80 25 50 40.

this is a typical endianness problem, are you sure the file contains `int` in binary ?

What do you know about the order of the bytes in the array ?

What do you know about the byte order of the CPU you use ?

What do you know about the size of the `int` in the file and used by your compiler ?

And in fact *in the array the item is storage 80 25 50 40* is false except if `sizef(int)` is 1 and if `int` does not follow 2s complement (else 80 is a negative number)

> ```
> int size = 4000000;
> ```

how can you suppose `size * sizeof(int)` will be enough to get all the content of the file ?

You need to first get the size of the file to have the right value for `size` or to read per block until the end using `realloc` to increase the array when needed

> ```
> FILE *card = fopen(infile, "r");
> ```

Warning if you expect to run under Windows you need to use "rb" to read a binary file

---

From your remark saying the file is a jpeg file if the first four bytes are 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   if (argc != 2) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", *argv);
     return 0;
   }
   
   FILE * fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
   
   if (fp == 0) {
     perror("cannot open file");
     return 0;
   }
   
   unsigned char header[4];
   
   if ((fread(header, 1, 4, fp) == 4) &&
       (header[0] == 0xff) &&
       (header[1] == 0xd8) &&
       (header[2] == 0xff) &&
       (header[3] == 0xe0))
     puts("jpeg file");
   else
     puts("non jpeg file");

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out ./a.out
non jpeg file
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out /home/pi/Downloads/bl2.jpeg
jpeg file
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I try to use char (so i can storage byte to byte in the array) the problem is that the file supose to be the card memory of a camera and I must recover some .jpeg files. You know it is a jpeg image if the first four bytes are 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0 (the four byte can change) but if I storage the array in a char when I use if (temp2[i] == 0xff) when I compile there is an error that says "result of comparison of constant 255 with expression of type 'char' is always false"

Comment: @David that kind of information about the file is jpeg is missing in your question. Use `unsigned char` rather than `char` to avoid that, because visibly for your compiler `char` is signed

Comment: I even try to storage the items like char in one array and in an adiccional Array copy them as Int (so i can compare the array with 0xff) but when i do that the data is not consistent :(

Comment: @David `int` may not be on 32b and the CPU may not have the right endianness. Again use `unsigned char`

Comment: Yes you rigth that was the solution "Use unsigned char" I do not understan exactly why but I'm going to read about it. Thank you for your help Bruno :)

Comment: @David do you need more help to read all the file in case it is a jpeg file ?

Comment: Thank you four all your help Bruno I really appreciate it, with this solve I will continue with the excercise